# iphone app always lockup in device after login but works fine in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an iphone app that is working fine in iphone simulator.
It was successfully build and archive in Xcode 3.2
But when I install it in my ipad/iphone it always lockup after login.
I tried to add a popup message after hitting the login button before redirecting to menu page, but its still not working. No matter how I edit the code in the login button, remove the database connection and just show the popup message, it will always lockup.

I am using diawi.com to install the app. 
I am wondering what went wrong, when the app is working fine in the iphone simulator. I also clean the project before the build.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you run the app on an iPhone directly from Xcode?

Comment: Xcode 3.2! Perhaps you should consider updating.